# Saving the Image from WPF control to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an application written in WPF 3.5 which at some point it saves the data in including an image in SQL Server, this is part of the code in saving the data (note `this.pictureImage` is a WPF `Image` control):-

```
using (SqlCommand command = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    String sqlInsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Info_Id (idNumber, FirstName, Nationality, Image) VALUES (@idNumber, @firstName, @nationality, @image)";

    command.CommandText = sqlInsertCommand;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNumber", this.cardIdTextBlock.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", this.fullNameTextBlock.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", this.nationaltyTextBlock.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", this.pictureImage);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

After I run this and click on the saving to DB button I got the following error.

> No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Controls.Image to a known managed provider

In the SQL Server database I have a row with (Picture (Image, null)).

Please advise me. And thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save an `Image` control in your database. Instead you should encode the image in the Image control's `Source` property by an appropriate bitmap encoder and store the encoded buffer as byte array.

```
byte[] buffer;
var bitmap = pictureImage.Source as BitmapSource;
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // or one of the other encoders
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
    buffer = stream.ToArray();
}

// now store buffer in your DB
```

Comment: So how come there is an Image data type in SQL Server 2012? also, there is no byte array data type in SQL, how will I be able to store it?

Comment: The [image data type in SQL server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) is actually a byte array. The linked article also says: `Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead`.